# NSNumber lose decimal digits

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to save a float into a NSNumber (the variable called ordered.value).
The problem is the decimal digits have been set to zero during the conversion.

Also I've add a log of 3 version of variable so you can see that the original float is correct. And then the NSNumber has lost the decimal digits.

this was my first attempt (the simpler version):

```
ordered.value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[o.valore floatValue]];
NSLog(@"%f,%f",[o.valore floatValue],[ordered.value floatValue]);
```

But I still lose decimal digits.
LOG:

```
2013-05-20 20:05:19.617 Piazzetta[9636:c07] 232.179993,232.000000
2013-05-20 20:05:19.617 Piazzetta[9636:c07] 20159.490234,20159.000000
2013-05-20 20:05:19.618 Piazzetta[9636:c07] 16.540001,16.000000
```

This is my second attempt (with NSNumberFormatter)

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
ordered.value = [f numberFromString:o.valore];
NSLog(@"%f,%f",[o.valore floatValue],[ordered.value floatValue]);
```

LOG:

```
2013-05-20 20:16:22.781 Piazzetta[9951:c07] 232.179993,232.000000
2013-05-20 20:16:22.782 Piazzetta[9951:c07] 20159.490234,20159.000000
2013-05-20 20:16:22.782 Piazzetta[9951:c07] 16.540001,16.000000
```

Comment: Can't see anything in the screen shot.  Please post code, if you want us to read it.

Comment: Why are you converting `o.valore` from a float to a string and back again? If this is not how your application works, please tell us what the actual context is so that we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're creating `ordered.value` in a weird way (as @bdesham noted, going to a string and back again) but the output of your NSLog indicates that `o.valore` *already* has all zeros after the decimal point.  Please post some code including the code that sets the value of `o.valore`.

Comment: What class is `o.valore`?

Comment: o.valore is a NSString

Comment: What is `ordered`? Did you happen to write your own getter for `value`  (i.e. do you have a method called `value`) in that class? If so, you should probably comment out that method and avail yourself of the standard, synthesized accessor methods.

Comment: How about just calling floatValue on the string itself? Should work for what you are doing.

Comment: By the way, the same is true for the setter for `value`. You should probably not have a method called `setValue` defined in whatever class `ordered` is. Let the compiler synthesize both accessor methods for you. It's impossible to tell whether the problem is in the setter or the getter from this snippet of code. Also, I hate the idea of a semantically vacuous property name of `value`, especially as it can only cause confusion with the existing `setValue` methods (e.g.  `setValue:forKey:`, etc.).

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing the type of every class and property you are using in your code.

Comment: Please turn the o.valore into a float first, then try: float x = [o.valore floatValue], then use that instead of using the method twice and update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried a simplified version of your code:

```
NSString *valore = @"232.179993";
NSNumber *ordered = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[valore floatValue]];
NSLog(@"Results: %f,%f",[valore floatValue],[ordered floatValue]);
```

Which works just as expected:

```
// Results: 232.179993,232.179993
```

This leads me to believe that it is being modified in your `ordered` object (probably via a setter or getter for your `value` property).

If you can't track that down, post the code for the setter and/or getter and we can take a look at that.

Comment: Problem solved:
Ordered is a class for CoreData entity, and value is an attribute, this is the reason of my NSNumber.
I forgot to set Float on CoreData.